# edit sitecore confirm box popping up when publish an item in draft state

Tags: sitecore-client, workflow

When we try to publish any Sitecore item in the draft workflow state then after clicking on publish we get a confirmation box as shown in the image.
I need to customize this popup (Edit its text and remove "OKAY" button). Please let me know where to find its code.

[image: Publishing warning for items in Draft workflow state]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the logic of this confirmation box under `Sitecore.Kernel` DLL. If you extract the DLL, you will find the logic of the confirmation box that is written under the class `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.PublishItem`. Under the below method, this is written.

```
private static bool CheckWorkflow(ClientPipelineArgs args, Item item)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, nameof (args));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, nameof (item));
      if (args.Parameters["workflow"] == "1")
        return true;
      args.Parameters["workflow"] = "1";
      if (args.IsPostBack)
      {
        if (args.Result == "yes")
        {
          args.IsPostBack = false;
          return true;
        }
        args.AbortPipeline();
        return false;
      }
      SiteContext site = Factory.GetSite("publisher");
      if (site != null && !site.EnableWorkflow)
        return true;
      IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider;
      if (workflowProvider == null || workflowProvider.GetWorkflows().Length == 0)
        return true;
      IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);
      if (workflow == null)
        return true;
      WorkflowState state = workflow.GetState(item);
      if (state == null || state.FinalState)
        return true;
      args.Parameters["workflow"] = "0";
      if (state.PreviewPublishingTargets.Any<string>())
        return true;
      SheerResponse.Confirm(Translate.Text("The current item \"{0}\" is in the workflow state \"{1}\"\nand will not be published.\n\nAre you sure you want to publish?", (object) item.DisplayName, (object) state.DisplayName));
      args.WaitForPostBack();
      return false;
    }
```

Now What you can do is create your own processor and use yours in the case of the OOTB given below. For this, you need to create a patch.

```
<command name="item:publish" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.PublishItem,Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

For the whole implementation, you can refer to this blog.

https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/09/21/looking-for-ways-to-customize-warning-messages-in-sitecore-content-editor/

Finally when it uses `SheerResponse.Confirm` then it will show the confirmation box like it is showing. So if you don't want to show the buttons then you can use `SheerResponse.Alert`.